# selecting rows dynamically in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to pick the number of rows dynamically for my standard deviation calculation in VBA.

Currently I have the following code:

```
Sub Stdev()

Dim x as integer
x=10
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=STDEV(R[1]C:R[5]C)"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=STDEV(R[1]C:R[x]C)"'this is my attempt at dynamic calculation
End Sub
```

How do I correct it to select the number of rows as specified in x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "=STDEV(R[1]C:R[" & x & "]C)"
```

Comment: if I want to make it a function instead of a sub, how do I do that?

Comment: what do you want as input and as output of the function?

Comment: As input, I want the flexibility to select random range of rows (say 1 to 30 or 4 to 19 etc., so I pass the beginning and ending row number as parameters to the function), and I want to get the standard deviation as output of that specified range of cells.